# Display:Block; causes row width to change... and I can't fix it

Tags: html, css, html-table

Got some simple HTML and CSS... I'm trying to separate the table into blocks. The reason for this is actually that eventually I want to use a jQuery slider on this. However, for now I have simplified the problem. The following code causes the heading rows to appear at full width, while defined in bodies below are shrunk and pushed to the left.

If you simply remove the single line Display:Block; from the CSS all the rows appear at the correct width. I'm not sure why. Been looking it for hours now!

Advice appreciated.

```
<table id="spud">
    <style type="text/css">
    #spud {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width:100%;
    }

    #spud th {
        padding: 10px 8px;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #6678b1;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    #spud td {
        padding: 6px 8px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    }

    #spud tbody td {
        text-align:center;
        width:100%;
    }


    #spud .time_period {
        font-weight: bold;
        background: #efefef;
    }

    #spud .time_period_rows {
        display:block;
    }

    #spud .time_select td:hover {
        background-color: #b0b0b0;
    }

    #spud tbody tr:hover {
        background: #eee;
    }
    </style>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="time_select">
            <td id="morning_rows_toggle" class="time_period">Morning</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="time_period_rows">
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="time_select">
            <td id="afternoon_rows_toggle" class="time_period">Afternoon</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="time_period_rows">
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="time_select">
            <td id="evening_rows_toogle" class="time_period">Evening</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="time_period_rows">
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What is the effect you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Why is you style block embedded within your table?

Comment: Table cells can't be displayed as block (no box-model on table cells). Their natural behaviour is: display: table-cell.

Comment: if you remove the line Display:Block; everything appears at the same width. This is exactly what I want. However, I need the Display:Block; in there because it's needed for the jQuery slider... so in a nutshell, is there a way to keep the Display:Block; in there and restore the full width to all rows. Thanks

Comment: "I'm trying to separate the table into blocks" -> I don't quite understand this? What are your trying to achieve?

Comment: I want 3 seperate headers if you like... 'morning', 'afternoon' , 'evening'... this is for a booking form... eventually, when you click on one of those, the available booking times will slide out below (and the others will slide up and hide)...

Comment: No problem here in IE9. What browser do you use?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Answer (score 0):

From your comment I think I understood the whole picture, but I think you have complicated your code. Since you are using jQuery, you should use [accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#default) instead of slide up/slide down.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/WgWsM/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3 class="time_period"><a href="#">Morning</a></h3>
    <div>
       <table>
        <tbody class="time_period_rows">
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
        </tbody>                   
        </table>           
    </div>
    <h3 class="time_period"><a href="#">Afternoon</a></h3>
    <div>
        <table>
        <tbody class="time_period_rows">
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>           
        </tbody>
        </table>          
    </div>    
    <h3 class="time_period"><a href="#">Evening</a></h3>
    <div>
        <table>
        <tbody class="time_period_rows">
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>
        <tr><td> row </td></tr>           
        </tbody>
        </table>          
    </div>    
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion();
});
```

Comment: Thanks SKS. I will try that. Accordion sounds pretty much exactly what I'm trying to achieve! Thank you.